# can't find merges folder with cordova

Tags: cordova

In [the documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0//guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) they keep talking about the *merges* folder.

Like *merges/android*, is this the *platforms* folder?

Cause I have *platforms/android* and *platforms* is the only folder with *android* folder.

And if *platforms* is the merges folder, then why don't they talk about the *platforms* folder?

(it might be obvious but I just want to make sure)

Search "Using merges to Customize Each Platform" at the link above to see what section I mean.

This is my current structure:

[image]

Comment: did you use `cordova create SomeName` to start your project?

Comment: yes. And that works. I can emulate on both android and iOS simulater and run on my iphone. Do you mean you actually have a folder called `merges`?

Comment: Backticks are a reserved markdown for code only on this site. I've fixed your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `merges` folder should be a top-level folder in your project, i.e. next to your platforms and www folders. If it doesn't exist you can just create it yourself.

In general you should consider the platforms folder as 'read-only'.

For more info on the merges folder you can read the [documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface_using_merges_to_customize_each_platform).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question and found out, that it has been removed in 3.5.0:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6709

http://markmail.org/message/vqzzxnhk7yosmabj

Comment: yeah I think the documentation is a bit outdated now and then.